# A "group" analogy of the Gelfand Naimark theorem

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, noncommutative-geometry

Are there two compact Hausdorff topological spaces $X,Y$ which are not homeomorphic spaces but the following two groups are isomorphic groups?
$C(X, \mathbb{H}^2)$ and $C(Y,\mathbb{H}^2)$
where $\mathbb{H}^2$ is the Poincare upper half plane whose group structure is the semi direct product of $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{R}^+$ via  the standard action of $\mathbb{R}^+$ on additive group $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is true.  Let us fix a compact Hausdorff space $X$ and write $G=C(X,\mathbb{H}^2)$.  Let $A=[G,G]$; note that $A$ consists of all $f:X\to\mathbb{H}^2$ whose second coordinate is always $1$, and so from now on we will identify it with the ordinary additive group $C(X,\mathbb{R})$.  Each element of $G$ acts on $A$ by conjugation; let $R$ be the subring of $\operatorname{End}(A)$ generated by all these conjugations.  Note that the conjugation action of $g\in G$ is just multiplication by the first coordinate of $G$, considered as a positive element of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$.  So $R$ is naturally isomorphic to the subring of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ generated by the positive elements.  But every $f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a difference of positive elements (say, $f=(|f|+1)-(|f|-f+1)$), so $R\cong C(X,\mathbb{R})$.

So, we can canonically (functorially with respect to isomorphisms) construct the ring $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ from the group $C(X,\mathbb{H}^2)$.  By Gelfand duality, this ring determines $X$ up to homeomorphism (explicitly, $X$ is canonically homeomorphic to its space of maximal ideals with the Zariski topology).  So, the group $C(X,\mathbb{H}^2)$ determines $X$ up to homeomorphism.

Comment: Actually, you can more canonically obtain the ring $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ as a certain subring of the endomorphism ring of the group $[G,G]$.  I will edit to explain this later.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer.

Comment: Are evaluation maps the only group homomorphisms from $C(X, \mathcal{H}^2)$ to $\mathcal {H}^2$? How can one define some thing abstract in simillar way if appearence of abstract $C^*$  algebras?

Comment: there are non evaluation morphism but i am still thinking to a direct realization of $X$ from $C(X,\mathbb{H})$. How can one an abstract formulation of this non abelian group?

Comment: Well, you could define it as a group whose commutator is abelian, the ring of endomorphisms generated by conjugations is a commutative real C*-algebra, and via this action the group is a semidirect product of this C*-algebra and its group of positive definite elements.  But probably this is not as intrinsic as you would like.

Comment: very good Idea! I would like to define an abstract thing then show that under cerain condition this abstract object is $C(X,\mathbb{H}^2)$ for some compact space $X$.What would be those "certain conditions"?